# Setting up SWTableViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am trying to utilize the open source `UITableViewCell` subclass `SWTableViewClass` but am running into issues. I am receiving the response "redefinition of a cell with a different type *_strong vs UITableView *_strong" Here is my code:

```
 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"FactorCell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    }

    SWTableViewCell *cell = (SWTableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        NSMutableArray *leftUtilityButtons = [NSMutableArray new];
        NSMutableArray *rightUtilityButtons = [NSMutableArray new];

        [leftUtilityButtons addUtilityButtonWithColor:
         [UIColor colorWithRed:0.07 green:0.75f blue:0.16f alpha:1.0]
                                                 icon:[UIImage imageNamed:@"check.png"]];
        [leftUtilityButtons addUtilityButtonWithColor:
         [UIColor colorWithRed:1.0f green:1.0f blue:0.35f alpha:1.0]
                                                 icon:[UIImage imageNamed:@"clock.png"]];
        [leftUtilityButtons addUtilityButtonWithColor:
         [UIColor colorWithRed:1.0f green:0.231f blue:0.188f alpha:1.0]
                                                 icon:[UIImage imageNamed:@"cross.png"]];
        [leftUtilityButtons addUtilityButtonWithColor:
         [UIColor colorWithRed:0.55f green:0.27f blue:0.07f alpha:1.0]
                                                 icon:[UIImage imageNamed:@"list.png"]];

        [rightUtilityButtons addUtilityButtonWithColor:
         [UIColor colorWithRed:0.78f green:0.78f blue:0.8f alpha:1.0]
                                                 title:@"More"];
        [rightUtilityButtons addUtilityButtonWithColor:
         [UIColor colorWithRed:1.0f green:0.231f blue:0.188 alpha:1.0f]
                                                 title:@"Delete"];

        cell = [[SWTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle
                                      reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier
                                  containingTableView:tableView
                // For row height and selection
                                   leftUtilityButtons:leftUtilityButtons
                                  rightUtilityButtons:rightUtilityButtons];
//        cell.delegate = self;

}

    DDFactor *factor = [_decision factor:indexPath.row];

    [[cell textLabel] setText:[factor title]];


    return cell;

}
```

Comment: You are declaring `cell` twice, once as `UITableViewCell` and second time as `SWTableViewCell` in the same method.

Comment: here you are trying to get cell two times from queue of reusable cell that might lead you to that error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are redeclaring a variable `cell` twice. Your code should be something like:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"FactorCell";

    SWTableViewCell *cell = (SWTableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        // making a guess here as to how to initialize SWTableViewCell
        cell = [[SWTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    }

    // ..

}
```