# How to use/import SWTableViewCell library

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I want to use 3rd party library "[Here](https://github.com/CEWendel/SWTableViewCell)".

My code is not producing any error, it can displaying the cell but the swipe isn't working. My suspect is, I'm missing something when importing the library.

I've read how to implement this library in "[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20136881/edit-and-delete-button-uitableview)" and "[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19420750/setting-up-swtableviewcell)". But none of them tell me how to import the library.

"[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Afa0e.png)" is my project structure showing how i import the library:

In `viewController.h`:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "SWTableViewCell.h"

@interface ViewController : UITableViewController <UITableViewDelegate,         UITableViewDataSource, SWTableViewCellDelegate>

@end
```

In `viewController.m`:

```
#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
// Return the number of rows in the section.
return [self.letterData count];
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath     *)indexPath {
 NSLog(@"cell selected at index path %ld:%ld", (long)indexPath.section,   (long)indexPath.row);
NSLog(@"selected cell index path is %@", [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow]);

if (!tableView.isEditing) {
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
}
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
//    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"Cell";
//    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"Cell";

SWTableViewCell *cell = (SWTableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

if (cell == nil) {

    cell = [[SWTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle     reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    cell.leftUtilityButtons = [self leftButtons];
    cell.rightUtilityButtons = [self rightButtons];
    cell.delegate = self;
}

cell.textLabel.text = self.letterData[indexPath.row];

return cell;

return cell;
}


- (NSArray *)rightButtons
{
NSMutableArray *rightUtilityButtons = [NSMutableArray new];
[rightUtilityButtons sw_addUtilityButtonWithColor:
 [UIColor colorWithRed:0.78f green:0.78f blue:0.8f alpha:1.0]
                                            title:@"More"];
[rightUtilityButtons sw_addUtilityButtonWithColor:
 [UIColor colorWithRed:1.0f green:0.231f blue:0.188 alpha:1.0f]
                                            title:@"Delete"];

return rightUtilityButtons;
}


- (NSArray *)leftButtons
{
NSMutableArray *leftUtilityButtons = [NSMutableArray new];

[leftUtilityButtons sw_addUtilityButtonWithColor:
 [UIColor colorWithRed:0.07 green:0.75f blue:0.16f alpha:1.0]
                                            icon:[UIImage imageNamed:@"check.png"]];
[leftUtilityButtons sw_addUtilityButtonWithColor:
 [UIColor colorWithRed:1.0f green:1.0f blue:0.35f alpha:1.0]
                                            icon:[UIImage imageNamed:@"clock.png"]];
[leftUtilityButtons sw_addUtilityButtonWithColor:
 [UIColor colorWithRed:1.0f green:0.231f blue:0.188f alpha:1.0]
                                            icon:[UIImage imageNamed:@"cross.png"]];
[leftUtilityButtons sw_addUtilityButtonWithColor:
 [UIColor colorWithRed:0.55f green:0.27f blue:0.07f alpha:1.0]
                                            icon:[UIImage imageNamed:@"list.png"]];

return leftUtilityButtons;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell     forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
// Set background color of cell here if you don't want default white
}

#pragma mark - SWTableViewDelegate

- (void)swipeableTableViewCell:(SWTableViewCell *)cell scrollingToState:(SWCellState)state
{
switch (state) {
    case 0:
        NSLog(@"utility buttons closed");
        break;
    case 1:
        NSLog(@"left utility buttons open");
        break;
    case 2:
        NSLog(@"right utility buttons open");
        break;
    default:
        break;
}
}

- (void)swipeableTableViewCell:(SWTableViewCell *)cell didTriggerLeftUtilityButtonWithIndex:(NSInteger)index
{
switch (index) {
    case 0:
        NSLog(@"left button 0 was pressed");
        break;
    case 1:
        NSLog(@"left button 1 was pressed");
        break;
    case 2:
        NSLog(@"left button 2 was pressed");
        break;
    case 3:
        NSLog(@"left btton 3 was pressed");
    default:
        break;
}
}

- (void)swipeableTableViewCell:(SWTableViewCell *)cell didTriggerRightUtilityButtonWithIndex:(NSInteger)index
{
switch (index) {
    case 0:
    {
        NSLog(@"More button was pressed");
        UIAlertView *alertTest = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Hello" message:@"More more more" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"cancel" otherButtonTitles: nil];
        [alertTest show];

        [cell hideUtilityButtonsAnimated:YES];
        break;
    }
    case 1:
    {
        // Delete button was pressed
        NSIndexPath *cellIndexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForCell:cell];

//            [_testArray[cellIndexPath.section] removeObjectAtIndex:cellIndexPath.row];
        [self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[cellIndexPath]     withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationLeft];
        break;
    }
    default:
        break;
}
}

- (BOOL)swipeableTableViewCellShouldHideUtilityButtonsOnSwipe:(SWTableViewCell *)cell
{
// allow just one cell's utility button to be open at once
return YES;
}

- (BOOL)swipeableTableViewCell:(SWTableViewCell *)cell canSwipeToState:(SWCellState)state
{
switch (state) {
    case 1:
        // set to NO to disable all left utility buttons appearing
        return YES;
        break;
    case 2:
        // set to NO to disable all right utility buttons appearing
        return YES;
        break;
    default:
        break;
}

return YES;
}
```

Comment: Your cell with identifier "Cell" -- what is its class in interface builder? Is it SWTableViewCell?

Comment: thanks @stevesliva, your clue solving my problem.
how i closed this thread as i already solve it?

Comment: You could answer it yourself. "I needed to set the cell's class in IB" or "the cell identifier in IB was incorrect" ... every answered question may help someone else